# Kibana Elasticsearch 6.4 basic security

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm really confused when I'm reading the documentation of security. I would like to protect the kibana with username and password. When I'm reading docs there is no mention that is free or not. Only the things with AD or Ldap that I'm aware are paid. So my question is: is it allowed to use basic security for free? Do I need to install an additional plugin for that if I use ELK 6.4.x?

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend Search Guard (https://search-guard.com/product/) community edition. This is a free and Apache 2 licensed feature rich open source security plugin for Elasticsearch which also comes with a Kibana plugin. Username/Password protection as well as SSL support is also free.

For advanced features like federated authentication, LDAP/AD and Audit logging you need to purchase a license.

Github link: https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard

Answer (score 0):

You need x-pack plugin for user & role based access to secure Kibana. X-pack is not free but I believe they have like a 30-day trial period.

Answer (score 0):

The security feature in the Elastic Stack is not free, you need a license for that, but if your goal is to set a username and password for acessing kibana there are other alternatives.

You can try the Community Edition of Search Guard, a security plugin for the elastic stack, or you can use nginx to secure the acess to kibana and other endpoints of the elastic api, as described on this post on the elastic blog: https://www.elastic.co/blog/playing-http-tricks-nginx

Comment: I do not recommend using a proxy linke nginx. Here is why: https://search-guard.com/elasticsearch-proxy-security/